# Regex: Previous statement must have mached at least 1 character

Tags: php, regex, perl, string-matching

I have a case-insensitive regex:

`f?a?(x|csim)?(mob)?(ile\s*?)?(tel)?(e)?(phone|p|t|m)?\s*?:?\s*?(\s*?\(*?\d\)*?){8,10}`

And here are my test cases:

I want these to match:

- Tel: 9555 5454
- telephone 08 9555 5454
- mobile 0411111 111
- Mob 0411 111 111
- Mobile : (0411) 111 111
- Telephone: (08) 9555 5454
- M0411111111
- phone : (08) 9555 5454
- p : (08)95 55 54 54
- T:0895555454
- Facsimile: (08) 9555 5353
- Fax 95555353
- F 95 55 53 53

But I don't want these to match

- 0411 111 111
- (08) 9555 5454
- 0411111111

Basically, I want to match things I identify as being a phone number, but **only** if they are prepended by an identifier to that effect.

My regex will successfully match the prefixed identifier, but because the whole thing is non-greedy, the "non-matching" test cases fail, because my regex specifies "match the prefix if it is there, but don't require it".

Any ideas?

- Please note: I am using the Perl/PHP version of regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a positive lookahead at the start of the match, for something other than space, digit, parentheses or colon

so your:

```
f?a?(x|csim)?(mob)?(ile\s*?)?(tel)?(e)?(phone|p|t|m)?\s*?:?\s*?(\s*?\(*?\d\)*?){8,10}
```

becomes:

```
(?=[^\s\d:()])f?a?(x|csim)?(mob)?(ile\s*?)?(tel)?(e)?(phone|p|t|m)?\s*?:?\s*?(\s*?\(*?\d\)*?){8,10}
```

However, this doesn't help the axilep problem as pointed out by pmakholm - his solution of explicit alternatives is much nicer to read, and less likely for you to leave some weird edgecase open.

Comment: You need to exclude `:` from the look-ahead too. Othewise probably a better solution then my look-behind solution which would probably require the match to be anchored at the start of the string.

Comment: Hi Cebjyre. Very good idea, in the end I went with this: `(?=[^\s\d\(:])f?a?(x|csim)?(mob)?(ile\s*?)?(tel)?(e)?(phone|p|t|m)?\s*?:?\s*?(\s*?\(*?\d\)*?){8,10}` which is like yours, but takes into account the opening brackets of the area code.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed parens based on pmakholm's `:` suggestion - included it in the description in the first paragraph, but left it out of the actual regex somehow. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

My advise is to keep regular expressions simple. Your current regexp already include the required prefixes, but the work to minimize the size of the regexp has incidentally made them optional.

If you keep the minimization to a minimum it would help:

```
\b(tel(ephone)?|mob(ile)?|facsimile|fax|[tmpf]):?\s?(\(\d+\))(\d|\s)+
```

The would make the prefix non-optional and also prevent a lot of garbage to be accepted. For example:

```
axilep: (08) 9555 5454
```

Comment: Strictly speaking that string still satisfies your regex, but the `axile` part is non-matching - chucking a `\b` (word boundary assertion) at the front would sort you out though

Comment: Thanks pmakholm, I appreciate your level of completeness and I do accept that my regex may match some funky edge cases. I might consider matching more literally. The particular problem I'm working on here though, it's unlikely to matter much. I'm doing a statistical analysis of word usage in helpdesk requests and I'm stripping out things like our common email footer and anything that looks like a phone number. But thank you, I didn't catch the axilep problem

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
(f?a?(x|csim)?(mob)?(ile\s*?)?(tel)?(e)?(phone|p|t|m)?)(?(1)\s*?:?\s*?(\s*?\(*?\d\)*?){8,10})
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to answer you question literally: You can do it by adding a zero-width look behind assertion matching a single character between the part of the regexp matching the prefix and the rest:

```
f?a?(x|csim)?(mob)?(ile\s*?)?(tel)?(e)?(phone|p|t|m)?(?<=.)\s*?:?\s*?(\s*?\(*?\d\)*?){8,10}
```

This means that after having found a match for the prefix it takes a second look to see if there is actually a character.